# drupal: how to assign the presets imagecache to different outputs of the modules?

Tags: image, drupal, image-processing

I have a drupal site to continue from another programmer, What I recently can't figure out what to do is where it is assigning the presets from imagecache to the blocks for example I have last news posted - uses a preset from the image posted on the article then on the front page i have a gallery with some articles that uses other preset , and so on.. I just can't figure out where are assigned..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal they are defined in numerous places.

1. In **configuration**: Admin › Content › MyContentType › Display Fields.
2. In the **theme functions**. e.g. a function called theme_mymodule_someblock() would return rendered HTML. Inside that function, imagecache can be called to generate an *img*-tag. Search for `theme('imagecache',...)`.
3. In **template preprocessors**: e.g. many themes will override the user-picture preprocessor to build their own. Aquia has an example of such a preprocessor. In those processors you will then see imagecache being called trough `theme('imagecache', ...)` to build an img tag.
4. In the **template files** often themers decide to ignore all above, ignore all settings and preprocessed and defaults and simply print a `theme('imagecache', ...)` result in one of the many `tpl.php`.